# Number of roots to given equation?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I need to find the number of roots to the equation $$2^x+2^{x-1}+2^{x-2}=7^x+7^{x-1}+7^{x-2}$$

How do I go about doing this? Definitely taking logarithms won't be of any help, the bases would be different on both sides.

With some rearranging, I got $$\frac{2^x}{7^x}=\frac{57 \times 4}{49\times 7}$$
Does this form help to get any solutions?

Comment: *Now* apply logarithm

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Which base would I take? $\frac{2}{7}$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have done all the hard work by getting to $$(\frac{2}{7})^x=\frac{57 \times 4}{49\times 7}.$$

To find $x$ you can take logs to whatever base you wish. However, you require the **number** of roots. The function $y=(\frac{2}{7})^x$ is a continuous and decreasing function on the positive real axis and so takes each positive value from 1 to zero precisely once.

Therefore your equation has precisely one root.

Comment: Could you elaborate your reasoning...why does it take each positive value?

Comment: You were quite right to query what I said - is the above more understandable?

Comment: continuous and decreasing function.

Comment: Yes, good point.

Comment: @S.Dolan Yes this makes sense...thank you

Comment: Alternatively, the expression $$\log_{\frac27} \bigg(\frac{57\times 4}{49\times 7}\bigg)$$ is only ever equivalent to one value.